# Как пишется слово "полумексиканская"?

Tags: орфография, лексика, словообразование, слитно-раздельно, сложные-слова

Правильно: "полумексиканская" (слитно) или "полу мексиканская" (раздельно)?

Comment: Пишется слитно.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно слитное написание: **полумексиканская** (см. [здесь](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B8_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/#id-4%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%C2%A7117)).

> Слитно пишутся также сложные слова с начальными частями, русскими и иноязычными, близкими к приставкам, напр.: *всепрощение*, *всеобъемлющий*, *ежемесячный*, *инопланетянин*, *инонациональный*, *лженаука*, *лжесоциалистический*, *общенародный*, *общепризнанный*, *полумесяц*, *полусладкий*, *полулежать*, *полушутя*, *самодостаточный*, *самолечение*; *панамериканский*, *квазинаучный*, *псевдоготика*, *псевдонародный*.

Даже нашёл для вас в "Нацкорпусе" несколько примеров, где упоминается смешанная национальность с *полу*.

*А пуще того ― ехать надо, а чтоб тронуться, ружьё-то никак не перехватить… А ментов-то всего двое, на одной машине… И тут этот куркуль **полуяпонский** взял и швырнул им деньги ― причём мои! [Алексей Шепелев. Кгыышфт Вшытундф-ТВ (2008) // «Волга», 2011]*

*А расскажу я вот что: оказалось, Миша Козаков ― не **полуеврей**, не **полурусский**, не четвертьфранцуз, а самый что ни на есть чистокровный АРТИСТ ― со всеми достоинствами и недостатками, присущими людям этого особого, Богом избранного, народа… [Григорий Горин. Иронические мемуары (1990-1998)]*

*Плевна ― небольшой и невзрачный **полутурецкий**, **полуболгарский** городишко; улицы тесны, кривы, грязны… [В. В. Гурьев. Письма священника с похода 1877-1878 гг. (1883)]*

*По крайней мере, мне, потому что я **полубелорус**, **полурусский**. [Двери в будущее распахивает наука // «Наука и жизнь», 2008]*

*Никто бы из нас, его тогдашних коллег, не мог бы представить себе, что этот довольно-таки первобытный, совсем не образованный **полуамериканец-полуангличанин**, бывший морской юнга, будет историческим Стэнлеем. [П. Д. Боборыкин. Воспоминания (1906-1913)]*